# How to make an element of a JSON array a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, json, servlets

If my AJAX call returns something like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": "Configuration ID",
        "type": "string",
        "editor": "editableText"
    }
}
```

And I have a variable defined as:

```
var editableText = $("<div/>").dynamicTableEditor({
editHandler: function(aData, aContext) {
   $("#save-data").html("Saving note: <strong>" + aData + "</strong>"); 
 }
 });
```

Is it possible to have to have a variable so that the output would be:

```
"name": "Configuration ID",
"type": "string",
"editor": $("<div/>").dynamicTableEditor({
            editHandler: function(aData, aContext) {
                $("#save-data").html("Saving note:  <
                    strong > " + aData + " < /strong>"); 
                }
            })
```

Comment: is this java or javascript? I think it's javascript... **java != javascript**. I'll edit to remove the `java` tag

Comment: Hey Max, you can add any type of function inside of the value of the object as long it return valid JSON, like string, int, array or object. I will recommend to create a function and return the function for code readability.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the string of

```
$("<div/>").dynamicTableEditor({
            editHandler: function(aData, aContext) {
                $("#save-data").html("Saving note:  <
                    strong > " + aData + " < /strong>"); 
                }
            })
```

Then it is possible. You can make it as a string and deserializate it any time you want.

I dont know what the return type of dynamicTableEditor() is. If it is a value which can be converted to a **String**, like abcde which can be converted to "abced", then the answer is yes.

You need to understand what the JSON is. JSON just make everything as a string. So if there is a variable you cannot convert to a string, then the answer is no.